# Unsatisfied dependency in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I want to implement JPA repositories as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). I think my problem is I want to use some functions from the JPA Repository itself and I `@Autorwired` it But I'm not completely sure

**Error Message:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addBothStudentsHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMajorRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'majorRepository' defined in io.asiam.tansiq.repositories.MajorRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#78f146b5' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'repositoryFragments'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#78f146b5': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customMajorRepositoryImplFragment': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customMajorRepositoryImpl' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customMajorRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'majorRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'majorRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1- tried to use *setter-based* `@Autowired` instead of *field-based* (But no change)

2- tried to use `@Lazy` also nothing changed

**Code: **

**CustomMajorRepository.java**

```java
public interface CustomMajorRepository {
    void addStudentToMajor(Student student, Major major);
    void increaseMajorLimit(UUID majorId, int amount);
}
```

**CustomMajorRepositoryImpl.java**

```java
    private MajorRepository majorRepository;

    public MajorRepository getMajorRepository() {
        return majorRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMajorRepository(MajorRepository majorRepository) {
        this.majorRepository = majorRepository;
    }
// rest of implementation details
```

**MajorRepository.java**

```java
@Lazy
public interface MajorRepository extends JpaRepository<Major, UUID>, CustomMajorRepository {
}
```

Comment: Does adding `@Repository` to `CustomMajorRepositoryImpl` or `MajorRepository` help?

Comment: You may need to use _constructor injection_, which is a best practice anyway.

Comment: @dan1st Unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I've just tried the constructor injection, it detected a cycle in my beans. how should I fix this?

Comment: Why you are trying to inject `MajorRepository` to `CustomMajorRepositoryImpl`?

Comment: @GeorgeLvov Because I need the save function from MajorRepository

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use dependency injection via constructor or setter, for example:

```
private MajorRepository majorRepository;

    public CostumMajorRepositoryImpl(MajorRepository mh) {
        this.majorRepository = mh;
    }
```

Here is the spring.io article about the setter and constructor injection:

https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/